# Using ASP.NET Dynamic Data site on Windows XP IIS?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-xp, dynamic-data

I have a Dynamic Data website built in Visual Studio 2008 using .NET 3.5 SP1.  The site works OK on my Vista machine, but I get the following error when running it on a Windows XP machine:

> Server Error in '/FlixManagerWeb'
>   Application.
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- The resource cannot be found. 
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /FlixManagerWeb
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

I have added the .* -> aspnet_isapi.dll mapping in the site config, made sure that it is an "application," but that did not help.  Anyone have any luck running a Dynamic Data website on Windows XP?  What (if anything) special is required to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 7 handles requests differently than IIS 5/6, and "default" routes are not handled by MVC in the classic mode.  While IIS 5/6 will work if you specify a specific page, it will not work out-of-the-box for typical MVC URLs (http://somesite/controller/action/parm).  It will ***only*** work if a) you include an extension in every request (.aspx or .mvc), or implement a wildcard mapping in IIS to pass EVERY request through the .NET processor.    [Steve Sanderson has a good writeup](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) on the options available.
FYI, we chose the wildcard option

Answer (score 1):

I've been running a Dynamic Data website on Windows XP, without any problems.  Nothing special was required to get it to work.

Sorry I can't be more helpful!

Comment: That is helpful.  At least now I know that it should be possible!